# Looking to remote access from other mac machine

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access

I have laptop with ubuntu 13.04. I want to access other machine display which is mac-mini. I am trying to get output via remote desktop access but I have no idea about it. Kindly give your opinion. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu can control an OS X machine remotely, using the default Remmina Remote Desktop Client application.

Setting up the Mac to be Accessed Remotely

On the Mac:

1. Open System Preferences (it's in the Apple menu)
2. Open the Sharing panel
3. Check the box Apple Remote Desktop
4. Click Access Privileges

Check the box VNC viewers may control screen with password, and enter a password

Click OK

Accessing the Mac From Ubuntu

On Ubuntu:

1. Launch Remmina Remote Desktop Client
2. Select Connection > New from menu
3. Select VNC - Virtual Network Computing as Protocol
4. Fill Server field with either IP address or hostname of the Mac

Optionally fill both User name and Password to make Remmina remember Your credentials

IMPORTANT: Set Color depth to High color (15 bit) or better, otherwise connection will fail

Click Connect (or Save to reuse it later)

Your Mac's desktop should appear on your screen.